# How to override Checkout sidebar and set custom customer attribute in it with address()?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I have created Custom attribute for Customer and override sidebar and Add Static Label but how to add my custom attribute value in its address() ?

I have not added that attribute as customer_address entity i've added it as customer entity only.

[image]

Comment: Is your custom attribute value present in window.customerData?

Comment: i've created my own customerData for bank account number attribute but that wasn't show any value in it

Answer (score 1):

I already faced this issue. Below are the links you can refer for custom development for Attribute

http://www.clounce.com/magento/magento-2-customer-attributes
http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html
http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer
http://www.learnmagento.com/magento-2-how-to-add-and-remove-custom-category-attribute/

It's going to take too much time. Finally i decided to go with

https://codecanyon.net/item/magento-2-ce-customer-attribute-system/16399784

Above plugin is Excellent, Within Budget & Very Useful. It's up to developer to decide.